nodejs AsyncLocalStorage misunderstanding
I stumbled upon AsyncLocalStorage and wrote some test code to play around with it.
My assumption was, that I can use it to set a state for a code chain and this state will magically exist in all code called inside of that chain without passing it explicitly as parameters. My assumption or code is wrong.
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from "async_hooks";

const als = new AsyncLocalStorage();

async function logStorePromise(prefix: string): Promise<void> {
    console.log(`${prefix} ${JSON.stringify(als.getStore())}`);
    await new Promise<void>(r => r());
}

als.run(
    { foo: "bar" },
    async () => {
        logStorePromise("start")
            .then(() => logStorePromise("then"));

        als.disable();
        console.log("> disabled");
        
    }
);

This logs
start {"foo":"bar"}
> disabled
end undefined
then undefined

My assuption was
start {"foo":"bar"}
> disabled
end undefined
then {"foo":"bar"}

Can someone explain to me where my misunderstanding lies?
I understand, that the then in my Promise chain places my () => logStorePromise("then") on the microtask queue. At the moment it is called, the Store is already disabled. Same as if I would use a global object that I clear when disabled is called.
Real use-case scenario
Let's say I have an express server and use the AsyncLocalStorage to add a trackingId to each incoming request.
Let's also say that request starts some asynchronous tasks and returns before they are finished.
After my test code above I would assume, that I should not clear the tracking id when the request is done as it would also remove that state from still running tasks.
But I feel like I should clear that state, because of memory and because I fear that express reuses that context somehow and the tracking id could still be set on some other call.

what's the point of await new Promise<void>(r => r())

@JaromandaX just added this as I didn't know if JS simplifies it in the background if the code is not really async.
